# Save Aspect Ratio in ImageView - Android

Tags: android, imageview, scale, aspect-ratio

I have an application which the user can capture images and then send them
to the server. I set the image to be as Base64 and then send it to the server.

In the application I have this screens:

1. Feed
2. Post Screen
3. Fullscreen Image (Landscape)

When the user enters to each screen I get from the server a Base64 and 
decode it to bitmap and set it to be the source of the imageview.

each screen has it's layout.
for the feed and post screens I set the imageview width and height to be hardcoded with some dp, and for the fullscreen image I set them to be fill_parent. 
Now for each imageview I set the scale type to : fitXY, but I see that the
pictures are streched and in the fullscreen mode I can see the pixels. 
I want to set the image to fit the xy but to be smooth as possible

I tried to set the adjustToBound to true and scaleType to cropCenter, fitCenter
and etc but it doesn't help.. how can I save the aspect ratio?

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: try setting [`android:adjustViewBounds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) property

Comment: @spezzino I already tried that..

Comment: @Elior ok, please create an MCVE so we can help

Answer (score 0):

In order for `adjustViewBounds` to work, one dimension of the `ImageView` needs to be set to a hard value like dp value or `match_parent`, and the other dimension needs to be set to `wrap_content`.  `adjustViewBounds` will make the `wrap_content` dimension adjust to be the right size to keep the image's aspect ratio.